# How to insert json field into mysql

Tags: mysql, go

I am trying to insert a json field into mysql. Its giving an error.Need your help here.

**My sample code class**

```
type StringInterfaceMap map[string]interface{}

type Movie struct {
    Id           int
    Name         string
    Casting      StringInterfaceMap
    Language     string
    Release_date time.Time
    Rating       float32
    IsAbove18    bool
}

func buildBrowserData() map[string]interface{} {
    return map[string]interface{}{
        "Actor": "Rajinikanth", "Music": "Deva",
        "resolution": struct {
            X int json:"x"
            Y int json:"y"
        }{1920, 1080},
    }
}
entry := model.Movie{
        Id:           6,
        Name:         ctx.QueryParam("Name"),
        Casting:      buildBrowserData(),
        Language:     ctx.QueryParam("Language"),
        Release_date: ctx.QueryParam("Release_date"),
        Rating:       1,
        IsAbove18:    true,
    }
```

**When trying to insert the above entry model am getting the folowing error in inserting casting type.
converting argument type: unsupported type model.StringInterfaceMap, a map**

Answer (score 2):

Have the custom map type implement the [`driver.Valuer`](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql/driver@go1.17.5#Valuer) interface, e.g.

```golang
func (m StringInterfaceMap) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    return json.Marshal(m)
}
```

And if you want to be able to also retrieve the json from the db you can implement the [`sql.Scanner`](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql@go1.17.5#Scanner) interface, e.g.

```golang
func (m *StringInterfaceMap) Scan(src interface{}) error {
    switch data := src.(type) {
    case []byte:
        return json.Unmarshal(data, m)
    case string:
        return json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), m)
    default:
        return fmt.Errorf("unsupported type: %T", src)
    }
    return nil
}
```